# modify gitignore after a pull with conflicts

Tags: git, egit

I am after doing a pull that has failed due to lots of conflicts in my `deploy` folder. I don't care about this folder and would like to ignore it. So I add `deploy/` to my .gitignore and pull again but I get the same error:

```
Checkout conflict with files: lots of files in deploy folder...
```

How can I fix this without losing my local changes(not in `deploy`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start ignoring files/folders that have already been added, you'll need to follow some additional steps after making required entry in `.gitignore`.

**After committing any changes** (VERY IMPORTANT), run the following commands:

```
git rm -r --cached .

git add . 

git commit -m 'ready to pull'
```

And that should be it.

It is a good idea to make a backup of mission critical files before doing anything which is potentially fatal, though the current scenario doesn't exactly fit in the category.